# Can I set up NGINX as a transparent SSL proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, https

Can NGINX be set up as reverse transparent proxy with SSL support?
I have a third-party application using HTTPS. 
For business purposes it is required to log some request data from HTTPS connections.

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.  http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

As you can see from the description of the `proxy_pass` directive, it allows redirection for both `http` and `https` protocols / address schemes.

I would imagine that you can even setup a general-purpose TLS interception device with nginx, through the use of `proxy_pass $scheme://$http_host;`.

Additionally, you might want to look into [OpenBSD relayd](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/usr.sbin/relayd/), which, [as per](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/usr.sbin/relayd/relayd.conf.5) [relayd.conf.5](http://mdoc.su/o/relayd.conf.5), officially supports "TLS inspection" and "SSL/TLS interception".

Answer (score 1):

short answer is yes. you can use nginx as a reverse proxy.
but your use case is not clear.

Comment: I have a Web application and a fat client that connects via HTTPS to this application. I need to capture some requests values and log them in a file for compliance purposes. I cannot modify the application. So I am looking for a kind of proxy that will intercept the request on the way and parse it. As the client does not support connections via proxy, the proxy has to be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TCP proxy if you mean HTTPS by SSL.

option 1:
LVS TCP Forwording

tested by kubernetes client/server certificate authentication.

option 2:
Use nginx stream proxy
http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html
not tested.

there are more options as long as the proxy don't disturb the HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a server to inspect SNI (server name identifier i.e. hostname) that comes in plain text in the first TLS packet sent by the client, and then transparently forward TCP packets to another server, without ever decoding the data. This is useful for hosting on the same IP multiple services that have their own SSL certificates that may not be known to the proxy at all.

I do not know of any proxies implementing this, and it won't work with clients that do not send SNI, or in the future when encrypted SNIs are adopted.

Normally all reverse proxies, including nginx, just decode the SSL and then make another SSL connection to the backend server (if https is being used in proxy_pass).

Comment: haproxy certainly does it.